# Adding String + Auto Increment - pandas, python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas, increment

I have a column within a dataframe that I need to update if another column is empty. The column is 'subscriberkey' and already has values in it. I need to update these value with a string + number. My intention is not to create a duplicate column.

The value needs to be unique, hence why I initially thought that appending the string+ a number would be the way to go.

```
Age Email            Subscriberkey
10  john@google.com  giririfndfieir
23                   kfkkfkfffrrrc
64  jane@ibm.co.uk   ifiririieiriei
```

for the second row, I would want the subscriberkey to be string+number+string
So far, I have tried the following:

```
 df.loc[df.Email == NULL, 'subscriberkey']= 'string'+.cumcount()+1+'string'
```

I will appreciate pointers on how best to achieve this.

Comment: what errors are you getting? 
can you put together a reproducible example?

Comment: I will edit my question to reflect this.

Comment: I have made the edit to my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
nullCond = df.Email.isnull()    
# or nullCond = (df.Email == "") it those are empty strings

df.loc[nullCond, 'Subscriberkey'] = "string" + nullCond[nullCond].cumsum().astype(str) + "string"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for having a go at this. I got an error when I tried it.: **Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly **

Comment: Updated the type conversion part. Need to convert the int to str with `astype()`, you can check if that works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This worked well. I have a slightly different requirement meant. Not sure if to open a new question. Assuming I wanted to label all the collumns of the subscriber key to give string + number ie. no condition, how would I go about it?

Comment: You can use a list comprehension to construct a list of strings. something like `df['Subscriberkey'] = ["string" + str(i+1) for i in range(df.Subscriberkey.size)]`

Answer (score 0):

consider `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(EMAIL_ACQ_DT=['key1', None, 'key2', None, 'ke3', 'key4', None, None]))
print(df)

  EMAIL_ACQ_DT
0         key1
1         None
2         key2
3         None
4          ke3
5         key4
6         None
7         None
```

---

```
fill_keys = df.groupby(df.EMAIL_ACQ_DT.isnull()).cumcount().apply('key{}_'.format)
df['subscriberkey'] = df.EMAIL_ACQ_DT.fillna(fill_keys)
print(df)

  EMAIL_ACQ_DT subscriberkey
0         key1          key1
1         None         key0_
2         key2          key2
3         None         key1_
4          ke3           ke3
5         key4          key4
6         None         key2_
7         None         key3_
```

Comment: Curious if this came from Responsys?

Comment: @Data_Kid I have no idea what you are talking about... so I'm guessing no :-)